# Read card information from a swipe machine for magnetic strip or chip card in java web application

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to develop a Spring MVC based web application with following requirements.

1. User will swipe his/her magnetic strip or chip card on a card swiping machine.
2. The machine will read card information on card and will transport the same to my web application.

My questions are.

1. Is it possible to transport information from swipe machine on internet (Obviously the machine is connected to internet)
2. How do I configure the swipe machine to so it would transport information to my web application (should I expose a rest web service).
3. How do I decode the data which is transported by swipe machine in my Spring controller or web service

Thanks you very much for any help
Anant

Comment: Most (if not all) readers are usually mounted in the OS as a keyboard. So you can almost certainly simply use a textbox. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading a mag strip (there are 3 of them in a card) is a simple job and you can rely on the driver that comes with the machine, or if you feel adventurous, break out the RxTx java library.

It is basically a bunch of letters and numbers - check wikipedia for the format of the CRC - but back to your questions:

1. Yes. Done that. Pretty simple. The machine has configurations that allow it to dial up or open a secure connection with a server.
2. Which number it will dial up or which service it will call is all configurable. Merchant will require you to provide your own machine and won't let you touch their existing machines.
3. Decoding is simple. The swiper comes with a driver and you can use it. However, if you have your own machine (which you will need) then decoding is not needed. The swiper will either call a server at the merchant (the case for restaurants or supermarkets) or it will open an HTTPS connection with the server and send all the data that it is in the card. Your server will get the data in plain text, so no need to read it manually.

Comment: Thank you very much Alexandre for your helpful reply. So considering above reply my first step should be to search and implement hardware.

Answer (score 0):

```
Is it possible to transport information from swipe machine on internet (Obviously the machine is connected to internet)
```

The machine has to have output somewhere, where it does send data when doing something.

```
How do I configure the swipe machine to so it would transport information to my web application (should I expose a rest web service).
```

In documentation for machine, there should be info about what does it send and how. Everything else depends on this.

```
How do I decode the data which is transported by swipe machine in my Spring controller or web service
```

Same answer as for previous question.

Comment: Thanks libik. My first step is to search hardware once I get it I should be able to consider above information.